# 'Reformat code with dartfmt' action in Intellij Idea - 'failed to reformat code' message received

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I have tried to reformat my dart code in IntelliJ Idea using the dart reformatter ('Reformat code with dartfmt' action).

I receive a `failed to reformat code message` error, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in the code!

#### Edit

The error `message failed to reformat code` was I thought possibly something to do with the configuration of my dart plugin or something else...however the most common reason for this error I suppose is because the code cannot be formatted due to an error in the code making it impossible.

Comment: If it was just syntax error - than question has to be deleted

Comment: I think it could be useful, if you disagree though I will happily delete.  I had no idea initially what the error was referring too and had me stumped!  (hence the exclamation mark, possibly you may not find a user as 'silly' as me but if we do then they may find this useful!! (I guess the error was a little vague)